# How to correctly place my custom dot next to my custom number in a ordered list?

Tags: css, list

In an ordered list, I'm asked to display numbers in a different color as the list item, as well as adding a dot next to the number.

I managed to achieve this, but when the number becomes a 2-digits one (from 10 onwards), the dot isn't properly located.

Any idea how to fix that?

CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: item;

    li {
        position: relative;

        &::before {
            content: counter(item);
            counter-increment: item;
            color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1em;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 0.5rem;
        }
        &::after {
            position: absolute;
            content: '.';
            left: 12px;
            color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's my code in a pen](https://codepen.io/Draikin1/pen/WmjXPO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use the after pseudoelement: change the `::before` like this, by adding the dot at the end of the `content`

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: item;

    li {
        position: relative;

        &::before {
            content: counter(item) ".";
            counter-increment: item;
            color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1em;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 0.5rem;
        }

    }
}
```

In this way the position of the dot will always follow the number, no matter how many digits you have.

> [Codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLmEGm)